# How do I prevent the back space key from going back a page in angular2?

Tags: angular

When a user is entering a text input on a form, if they press the back key too many times, it'll go back a page in the history.

Answer (score 1):

You can just bind to the window.keydown event in ngAfterContentInit like this:

```
public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
 window.addEventListener('keydown', (e: any) => {
   if (e.which === 8 && e.target.tagName == 'input') {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
 })
```

}